# How to load EST timezone properly with the correct daylight saving time UTC shift?

Tags: go, time

How to load EST timezone properly with the correct daylight saving time UTC shift?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile | log.LstdFlags)
    const newYorkTimeZone = "EST"
    newYorkLoc, err := time.LoadLocation(newYorkTimeZone)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: %+v\n", err)
        return
    }
    ny := time.Now().In(newYorkLoc)
    log.Println("ny", ny)
    log.Println("utc", ny.UTC())
}
```

prints:

```
go run main.go
2021/03/16 19:12:54 main.go:17: ny 2021-03-16 11:12:54.472058 -0500 EST
2021/03/16 19:12:54 main.go:18: utc 2021-03-16 16:12:54.472058 +0000 UTC
```

So it gives 5 hours time shift with UTC. But I expect it to be 4 hours because today (March 16 2021) [NY time zone difference with UTC](https://www.google.com/search?q=NY+time+zone+difference+with+UTC&rlz=1C5CHFA_enRU930RU930&oq=NY+time+zone+difference+with+UTC&aqs=chrome..69i57.761j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is 4 hours according to google.

Comment: "EST" means "Eastern **Standard** Time", i.e. defined as *not* daylight savings time.  Right now New York is on Eastern Daylight Time (EDT).  Do you literally want "Eastern Standard Time", or "whatever local time is in New York right now"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"EST" is Eastern Standard Time, standard meaning "not daylight saving time". Use location instead. That takes into account the daylight savings based on that location. In this case, use the location "America/New_York".